# Android emulator on AMD

Tags: android, android-emulator, amd-gpu

I got AMD a8 processor which is fine . when I try to test my app in android emulator , it showed a error that I should not select ×86  images for booting up. Then I selected arm images.  But it is still taking ages to boot and even after starting up, setup wizard is not responding.
There are many people with same problem in many forums. But no way to make it. 
Thanks in advance
Processor : amd A8 ,
Ram : 4gb ddr3
Os : windows 64bit
Processor variant :A8 -7410

Comment: Like this your question is not reproducible for anyone. You have to more details about your environment like OS, versions, CPU model, RAM and what you are doing.

Comment: Ok.   I will get my CPU details

Comment: You are at minimum RAM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38137784/295004 also have you tried Genymotion or Visual Studio Android emulator?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator

Comment: Tried genymotion , but then my windows crashed.  If I try again to download genymotion. Its showing about premium pack